# (closed) How change object value array to object value array object in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, next.js, arrayobject

i have a object value array like this:

```
{
    user: ["data1", "data2"],
    user2: ["data1", "data2"],
}
```

and i want change a **object value array** to **object value array object** like this:

```
{
    user: [{value: "data1", name: "data1", isChecked: false}, {value: "data2",  name: "data2", isChecked: false}],
    user2: [{value: "data1", name: "data1", isChecked: false}, {value: "data2",  name: "data2", isChecked: false}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the object using Object.entries that will give you an array with the [key, value] of each property of the object and after that just create a reduce function to build a new object that returns the modified array using a map function:

```js
const obj = {
    user: ["data1", "data2"],
    user2: ["data1", "data2"],
}
const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
 const [key, value] = curr

 return {
  ...acc,
  [key]: value.map(item => ({ value: item, name: item, isChecked: false}))
 }

}, {})

console.log(result)
```